# Can SQLAlchemy Core be used with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use a standard sqlAlchemy Core query such as the one below, with the Flask-sqlAlchemy module as instantiated with the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

For code re-use purposes, these type queries are what we need to use, where db.metadata is the db object for our existing db connection, without Flask-sqlAlchemy. We would like to be able to use these type queries as we do with SQL Alchemy ORM, **pythin** having to setup Models and Controllers as we would for Flask-sqlAlchemy.

```
node = Table('nodes', db.metadata, autoload=True)
qry = node.select().where(node.c.node_id == node_id)
res = qry.execute()
for row in res:
    data = dict(row)
```

Comment: **Yes**, it is possible. However in your example you are not even using `OMR`, but only `SQLalchemy Core`

Answer (score 1):

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api

> This class also provides access to all the SQLAlchemy functions and classes from the sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.orm modules. So you can declare models like this:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    pw_hash = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

> You can still use sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.orm directly, but note that Flask-SQLAlchemy customizations are available only through an instance of this SQLAlchemy class. Query classes default to BaseQuery for db.Query, db.Model.query_class, and the default query_class for db.relationship and db.backref. If you use these interfaces through sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.orm directly, the default query class will be that of sqlalchemy.

So, I would recommend using the Flask-SQLAlchemy classes, since they are thin wrappers around the base SQLAlchemy objects, with a couple additions to make it work more seamlessly with your Flask application. However as the documentation states, it is not preventing you from dropping down to the SQLAlchemy classes.

I did have a Flask app where we didn't use Flask-SQLAlchemy and just had the flask app call a [database interface](https://github.com/Mirantis/kostyor/blob/master/kostyor/rest_api.py#L70), and we used [pure SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/Mirantis/kostyor/blob/master/kostyor/db/api.py). The downside is that you then have to do some work to make it work with Flask's application context and [lifecycle](https://github.com/Mirantis/kostyor/blob/master/kostyor/rest_api.py#L36). Which may be what you are looking for, if you want to decouple the database layer from the Flask layer.

Comment: Our database has a a large number of tables and columns. Is there a way to use some combination of the declarative base and metadata to declare a module as mentioned above, without having to hard code hundreds of lines of code that would be subject to frequent chnage?

Comment: There might be a way for you to use metaprogramming to save some time and dynamically set the table metadata, but if your database layer is "subject to frequent change" you have a more fundamental problem. The database layer is not a layer where rapid change is desired

Comment: You may want to look into SQLObject, that is a library I used a long time ago where it did a lot of database introspection to dynamically create classes for each table, without a lot of code http://sqlobject.org/SQLObject.html#automatic-class-generation

Comment: Yes, that fundamental problem is called "development", we have to maintain a Flask based GUI for an app that is otherwise in constant development, and we need to be able to reuse the same queries as the app, which is stand-alone Python, and has nothing to do with Flask. But we share a database. So we are either the first to build a linked DB to use a Flask based GUI to control a stand-alone app, or we are doing it all wrong. And so far we still don't see any way to use the existing Flask DB connection for sqlAlchemy Core queries.

Comment: If you have multiple apps using the same database, I would recommend you team create a stable API, or a set of queries that can _don't_ change. Or create a microservice that serves as a middle layer between multiple apps and the database, so that you cut down on the amount of DB changes that get exposed to the higher layers.

Comment: We have dozens of servers, running a myriad of Python apps. Everything runs great. The odd man out is the Flask GUI. We just wanted to be able to use the same code for the GUI as we use for our core applications. Apparently, that isn't a thing. The solution is just to skip Flask-sqlAlchemy altogether, and to roll your own session and connection controls via the scoped sessions from sqlAlchmey core. Although the SQLObjects looks like a solution to the Class issue for Flask-SQLAlchemy.